# How can I set height higher than 100% in a flexbox flex-column class div?

Tags: html, css, sass, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have created a grid with bootstrap, and in one of the columns I would like to have a grid of divs. Every div should become bigger on hover, and should go over surrounding ones.

Divs have images and text inside. There should be 3 divs on mobile (one above  the other, single div in every 'row') ,and 3 'rows' with 3 divs inline on bigger screens. I have achieved that by putting following classes on a bootstrap div that contains previously mentioned: col d-flex flex-column flex-md-row.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <p>Place for some other content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 ">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col d-flex flex-column flex-md-row justify-content- 
around">
          <div class="image-container">
            <div class="left">
               <img src="./img/flag.png" alt="">                     
            </div>
            <div class="main">
              <img src="some image" alt="">
              <p>Some text</p>                       
            </div>
            <div class="lower">
              <button class="btn">Link me</button>
            </div>
           </div> 
             /* two more .image-container divs */   
         </div>
       </div> 
      /* two more times the same: div.row, div.col.d-flex etc.*/                  
     </div>
   </div>           
 </div>
```

One major point is this: every div with image has two hidden divs on the sides, so when you hover over the div - the div kindda expands (hidden divs get the display: block), AND its content goes over  divs on the left and bottom (I have set z-index) without moving those surrounding divs.
  Everything works as I wanted, EXCEPT on the mobile where I have set flex-column direction. There divs simply don't expand towards bottom, only on the left. The hidden div on the bottom shows on hover INSIDE the parent, instead bellow and above the following lower positioned element.

SCSS:

```
.col-lg-3 {
display: none;
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    display: flex;
}
}

.image-container {
    margin:15px;   
    width: 250px;
    position: relative;
    .main {
        padding: 0 10px;        
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .lower {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: white;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 21%;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-top: none;
        padding: 0 10%;
        button {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: orange;
            color: white;
        }
    }
    .left {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: gray;
        left: -50px;
        top: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 50px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-right: none;
        img {
            width: 50%;
            margin: auto;
        }
    }
    &:hover {
        z-index:1;
        height: 115%;
        .lower, .left {
            display: block;
        }
    }
  }
```

Why is that happening, and how can I make it work the way I intended.
  Also, I would be very happy to hear if you have suggestions about other possible solutions for creating these get-bigger-on-hover divs.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, are you looking to increase the size of the tile in-place without affecting the layout of other. If yes, then I have created a small fiddle [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/saksham_malhotra/0w4nu8kq/).

This uses `flexbox` and `scale` transformation to increase the size of tile in-place.

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.tile {
  border: 1px solid #888;
  height: 190px;
  width: 190px;
}

.tile:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
</div>
```

A better approach would be to use CSS `grids`. It will allow you to evenly space out tiles around your workspace.

Comment: @LGSon did as you suggested